# Axis2 with WS-Notification

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, ws-notification

Does the JAX-WS implemented over Apache Axis2 offers the WS-Notification specification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [its modules list](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/modules/index.html), as of today Apache Axis2 supports the following WS-* standards:

- WS-Addressing (version 2005-08)
- WS-Reliable Messaging (version 2005) via [Sandesha2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/sandesha/index.html)
- WS-Security and related specifications (WS-SecureConversation, WS-SecurityPolicy, WS-Trust) via [Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/)

So, to answer your question: No, there is no support for WS-Notification in Axis2.

Comment: Thanks! I think that solution is the Apache Muse, or Apache Savan, although Apache Savan seems to be down.

Comment: Muse seems to have been retired to [the Apache Attic](http://attic.apache.org/), so Savan should be the better solution. I can access and download Savan, btw. Also, if this answers your question, could you mark it as accepted answer? You can do so by clicking the check box on the left side. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for details.